# Rails Understanding Associations Conceptually (Rendering and Posting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, has-many

I read the rails guide on associations and I have also gone through a bunch of questions here on SO and on reddit, but I am just not getting associations conceptually, I think. I have two specific issues I can use as examples from an app I am working on, but I am really just trying to understand what I am doing.

Models for these examples:

```
List
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :items
Item
        belongs_to :list
        belongs_to :user
User
        has_many :lists
        has_many :items
```

Issue 1: Rendering associations

I know that to show the related associations in a list I can do something like this in my view:

```
Users/show
    <%= render @list %>
Lists/_list 
    <ol> 
        <%= list.name %>
        <%= render list.items %>
    </ol>
Items/_item 
     <li><%= item.name %></li>
```

This seems like magic to me. I know I am calling user.list and then list.item, but when there are multiple Lists, how does rails know to separate them with the associated Items underneath? In my head when I see this code I anticipate the following as output:

```
<ol>    
  List(a)
  List(b)
  List(c)
    <li>item(a)</li>
    <li>item(b)</li>
</ol>
```

What I am trying to do is render each List as a Tab and render the associated Items as the tab content. Ultimately, I have multiple different List type models I want as tabs and matching multiple different Item type models to render as tab content.

**Edit:** I got rid of my second issue, since the post was long and it could be a separate post. Restating the above, how can a take the above collection and render it successfully in tabs where Lists are the tabs and the associated Items render as the content?
I am running into issues if I use the code like this in my Users/show:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col s12">
         <ul class="tabs">
                  <%= render @lists %>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <%=render @items %>
</div>
```

Lists/_list

```
     <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#tab_<%=list.id%>"><%= list.name%></a></li>
```

Items/_item

```
       <div id="#tab_<%=list.id%>" class="col s12"><%= item.name %></div>
```

If I try this, then my item partial gives me an error, because I can’t call list.id, and it will just render all of my items without displaying them as an associated collection with the Lists. If I nest this and put everything after the <%=render lists %> inside the list partial, then the collections work, but the closing tags end up causing issues. I am not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing collections to render has very little to do with associations per say - you should consult the [Layouts & Rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) instead.

When you call render with a collection (an array of model instances) Rails creates a loop and uses the [model name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html) and conventions to find the correct partial for each member of the collection.

Rails does not care that the collection came from an association.

### added:

Since the relationship between List and Item is bidirectional you can always access the list to which the item belongs by `item.list`:

```
# views/items/_item.html.erb
<div id="tab_<%= item.list.id %>" class="col s12">
  <%= item.name %>
</div>
```

Also notice that I removed the `#` in the beginning of the ID since its an invalid character for an element id.

Comment: I edited and updated my post to clarify what I am looking for more specifically. Thank you for the tip about layouts and rendering. I was really caught up on the associations issue. Actually, I had <%= render list.item**s** %> in my code, but I screwed up when making my post from memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot believe I was overlooking something so simple as what you added to your answer. I really, really appreciate it.